# Separar cadena con split y almacenar los datos solo en variables necesarias

Tags: java, string, split

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
String cadena=JTextField.getText();
String[] split=cadena.split("\\s");
String p1=split[0];
String p2=split[1];
String p3=split[2];
```

Como ven, el código separa la cadena en 3 palabras que son almacenadas en las variables p1, p2, p3.

El problema es que solo funcionará si he escrito **3** palabras en el *JTextField*, si escribo solo **2** palabras o **4** palabras me mandará un error.

Quisiera que si escribo(en el *JTextField*) una cadena con X cantidad de palabras en ella, dichas palabras **se almacenen una por una en una variable distinta**. De modo que no estoy limitado a escribir solo 3 palabras, sino todas las que necesite, incluyendo si escribo solo una palabra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se puede hacer con repetidos `String palabraN = split[x];`

Deberías hacer uso de una `lista simplemente enlazada`, o del `ArrayList<>` que son prácticamente lo mismo.

Sería algo como:

```
String cadena=JTextField.getText();

String[ ]split=cadena.split("\\s");

ArrayList<String> pal = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0; i < split.length; i++){ // no recuerdo si es length o length()
    pal.add(split[i]);
}
```

Queda en ti convertirlo a algo más eficiente como un `foreach`, buscar ejemplos de los `vector`, `arraylist` y `list`

Comment: eso fue lo que hice, logré mi objetivo gracias a ti, agregué varias cosas pero todo fue en base a eso del ArrayList que no había considerado, también tengo que decir que descarté la idea de almacenar los elementos en variables.